# Excel Macro Does Not Work When Running from Personal Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to create a macro that would get rid of several rows based on certain criteria. The macro works fine when I run it from a workbook but it does not work when I try to run it from the Personal Workbook. I want to be able to use the macro with all kinds of spreadsheets that I receive at work.
I put a control message to tell me if the macro is running on the active workbook rather than on the personal and it does show that it is running on the active workbook.
Here is the code:

```
Sub Delete_Unused_Rows()

Dim lRows As Long
Dim vbAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim sCriteria1 As Variant
Dim sCriteria2 As Variant
Dim sCriteria3 As Variant
Dim sCriteria4 As Variant
Dim sCriteria5 As Variant
Dim ImportantData1 As Variant
Dim ImportantData2 As Variant
Dim ImportantData3 As Variant
Dim ImportantData4 As Variant
Dim ImportantData5 As Variant
Dim Company_Name

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

MsgBox "The name of the active sheet is " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ActiveSheet.Name

  'Ask user for input
  sCriteria1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the criteria for 1-30 days." _
                                    & vbNewLine & "Type and Integer.", _
                                    Title:="Little Macro", _
                                    Type:=1)
'Exit if user presses Cancel button
  If sCriteria1 = False Then Exit Sub

  sCriteria2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the filter criteria for 31-60 days." _
                                    & vbNewLine & "Type and Integer.", _
                                    Title:="Little Macro", _
                                    Type:=1)
'Exit if user presses Cancel button
  If sCriteria2 = False Then Exit Sub

  sCriteria3 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the filter criteria for 60-90 days." _
                                    & vbNewLine & "Type and Integer.", _
                                    Title:="Little Macro", _
                                    Type:=1)
'Exit if user presses Cancel button
  If sCriteria3 = False Then Exit Sub

  sCriteria4 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the criteria for 91-120 days." _
                                    & vbNewLine & "Type and Integer.", _
                                    Title:="Little Macro", _
                                    Type:=1)
'Exit if user presses Cancel button
  If sCriteria4 = False Then Exit Sub

  sCriteria5 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the filter criteria for 120 + days." _
                                    & vbNewLine & "Type and Integer.", _
                                    Title:="Little Macro", _
                                    Type:=1)
'Exit if user presses Cancel button
  If sCriteria5 = False Then Exit Sub

row_number = 1


    Do
    'DoEvents
        row_number = row_number + 1
        Company_Name = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number)
        ImportantData1 = Sheet1.Range("E" & row_number)
        ImportantData2 = Sheet1.Range("F" & row_number)
        ImportantData3 = Sheet1.Range("G" & row_number)
        ImportantData4 = Sheet1.Range("H" & row_number)
        ImportantData5 = Sheet1.Range("I" & row_number)


        If ImportantData1 >= sCriteria1 Then
            With Range("E" & row_number).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Range("E" & row_number).Font.Bold = True
        End If

         If ImportantData2 >= sCriteria2 Then
            With Range("F" & row_number).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Range("F" & row_number).Font.Bold = True
        End If

         If ImportantData3 >= sCriteria3 Then
            With Range("G" & row_number).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Range("G" & row_number).Font.Bold = True
        End If

         If ImportantData4 >= sCriteria4 Then
            With Range("H" & row_number).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Range("H" & row_number).Font.Bold = True
        End If

         If ImportantData5 >= sCriteria5 Then
            With Range("I" & row_number).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Range("I" & row_number).Font.Bold = True
        End If


        If ImportantData1 < sCriteria1 And ImportantData2 < sCriteria2 And ImportantData3 < sCriteria3 And ImportantData4 < sCriteria4 And ImportantData5 < sCriteria5 Then
            Sheet1.Rows(row_number & ":" & row_number).Delete
            row_number = row_number - 1
        End If

       ' If IsEmpty(Company_Name) = True Then
       '  Exit Do
       ' End If

    Loop Until Company_Name = Empty

MsgBox "Completed"

End With

End Sub
```

This is what the Spreadsheet looks like:

[Spreadsheet Sample.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaIKJ.jpg)

Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: "Does not work" is not helpful - please describe the specific problem.

Comment: SJR, when I run the macro from the workbook, I can see through the debug that each variable is being assigned a value as the macro is checking every cell. For example, on the first iteration, the Company_Name variable get assigned "Customer 1" from cell A1, the "ImportantData1" gets assigned value "0.00" from cell E1. However, when I run it from the Personal Workbook, those variables get assign and "Empty" value. I hope that helps.

Comment: All sheet references should have a workbook reference (probably `activeworkbook`). In addition all these `Range("E" & row_number).Interior` should have workbook and worksheet references.

Comment: Also if possible better to declare your variables as specific types rather than `variant`.

Comment: SJR,  I'm new to programming so please bear with me. Question - how and where does the ActiveWorkbook reference go? also, I added the ".Interior" at the end  "Company_Name = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number).Interior" and received the following error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: What's `Sheet1`? That looks like a worksheet codename, which you should *not* be using if the macro is in the personal workbook.

Comment: BigBen, the `Sheet1` is referencing the active sheet1. I have a line `With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`, doesn't that indicate the Personal workbook to use the active workbook?

Comment: `Sheet1` is referencing the active sheet1... that is not correct. It's referencing a worksheet in the personal workbook. You might want to read up on [using `With` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-with-statements) too.

Comment: I'm very new at this and lots of it seems like a puzzle that I'm trying to put together. Any help is greatly appreciated.  How do I make it reference the active sheet rather that the one in the personal workbook? I put a MsgBox  to print the name of the active workbook and sheet and it gives me the name of the Active workbook not the name of the personal one.